# Magento 2 How can I hide Product Price in limit e.g From $61.00 To $77.00

Tags: magento2, product, admin

Actually I hide the Prices of all the products n I was expecting that the Limit Product price will be also hide but it was not hidden. I'm going to upload Image for you guys clearance. Thanks in Advance [image]

Comment: How did you hide?

Comment: Display the code how you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">    
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox">
        <plugin name="price_hide" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Price" sortOrder="1" disabled="false"/>        
    </type>
</config>
```

> Vendor\Module\Plugin\Price.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

    class Price
    {
        function aroundToHtml(\Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox $subject, callable $proceed) {         
                return '';
        }
    }
```

Comment: @asad khan If my answer solved your problem, click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer.